# ASM ByteCode Method Local Variables

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using Java/ASM and processing the byte code of a class, I want to get the data types of the locally defined variables.

I have written the basic `visitMethod`, But I am not sure how to get the data types of the locally defined variables .

```
public class CVisitor extends ClassVisitor{

public CVisitor(int api, ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
    super(api, classVisitor);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override 
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions)
{
    System.out.println(name);
    MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
    System.out.println("desc="+descriptor);    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You have to create you own (subclass of) `MethodVisitor` and return it. I suggest [taking the tour](https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR the local variable names are not present in the bytecode, so this is not possible to implement.

Comment: can I  get the data types of the variables? I am editing the question